# Bacon.js how to filter an event stream based on another property?

Tags: javascript, bacon.js

I have an event stream for when ENTER is presssed

```
var enter = 
  $('#text')
  .asEventStream('keydown')
  .filter(function(e){
    return e.keyCode === 13
  })
```

This works great. But, I want to only take action if ENTER is pressed and another property - textMatches - is true. How do I do this? I tried

```
var advance = textMatches.and(enter)
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean methods are defined for operations between two Properties, but `enter` is an EventStream. Properties can be used to filter EventStreams and the following should work for your use case:

```
var advance = enter.filter(textMatches)
```